# Why std::thread() passes arguments by value (and why the reason given by Dr. Stroustrup is incorrect)?

Tags: c++, reference, stdthread

Quoting from The `C++ Programming Language` (by Bjarne Stroustrup), page *1213*

> The thread constructors are `variadic templates` (§28.6). This implies that to pass a reference to a
> thread constructor, we must use a reference wrapper (§33.5.1).
>
> For example:
>
> ```cpp
> void my_task(vector<double>& arg);
> void test(vector<double>& v)
> {
>     thread my_thread1 {my_task,v};           //oops: pass a copy of v
>     thread my_thread2 {my_task,ref(v)};      // OK: pass v by reference
>     thread my_thread3 {[&v]{ my_task(v); }}; // OK: dodge the ref() problem
>     // ...
> }
> ```

The problem is that `variadic templates` have no problem to pass arguments by reference to a target function.

For example:

```cpp
void g(int& t)
{
}

template <class... T>
void f(T&&... t)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(t)...);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    f(i);
    return 0;
}
```

The only reason that `std::thread` passes by value is because the standard requires to use `std::decay` on the arguments.

Am I correct?

Can somebody please explain this quote by Stroustrup?

Comment: Sorry for late edit in the question. the comment was part of the quote by Stroustrup.

Comment: The very next paragraph starts "The problem is...".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing by reference by default would be a major foot-gun: when the thread accesses local variables, they may well be out of scope by the time that the thread runs, and it would have only dangling references. To make the use of values safer, the code must specify explicitly which variables are safe to access by reference in one of the ways that you showed.

Comment: Agree. but this is NOT the reason given by Stroustrup. I find the quote by Stroustrup incorrect and misleading. Am I correct?

Comment: Bjarne isn't always that precise ;)

Comment: But this is quite an amateurish statement. As a new beginner to C++, to find such a quote from the creator himself is very disturbing...

Comment: If the "this" in the quoted "this implies" refers to "variadic templates", then the statement is wrong. Is there no other context to which the "this" could refer?

Comment: https://apprize.best/c/programming_2/42.html for full context. "this", strictly, refers to "variadic templates", and given as the only reason why std::thread constructors pass their arguments by value.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem is that variadic templates have no problem to pass arguments by reference to a target function.

When you have a variadic template of this kind with a template parameter pack `T`, you can write the function parameter either as

```
T... t
```

or as

```
T&&... t
```

If you take the former form, then you can't pass-by-reference directly. `T` will always deduce to non-reference types. Also, you probably don't want this form as it always implies an extra copy/move.

If you use the second form `T&&` will *always* deduce to a reference. There is no possibility for it to deduce to a non-reference type and so it will *always* pass-by-reference.

However, abstractly, `std::thread`'s constructor should be able to pass the arguments by-reference as well as by-value to the new thread. So, naively, this interface can't enable both. Either the deduced references for `T&&` are always passed on as references or they are always used to construct `std::decay_t<T>` objects from them to pass on. There is no way to distinguish that in deduction.

So the only solution to support both is to encode whether or not you want pass-by-reference or pass-by-value in the type `T` itself. You could either decide that the default is pass-by-value and a wrapper type `std::reference_wrapper<U>` indicates pass-by-reference, or you could decide that pass-by-reference is the default and pass-by-value requires some kind of `value_wrapper<U>` wrapper type.

The former makes much more semantic sense and is safer, so that's what's always chosen in the standard library for interfaces that need to be able to do this abstract passing by-value as well as by-reference.

Comment: _"If you use the second form T&& will always deduce to a reference. There is no possibility for it to deduce to a non-reference type and so it will always pass-by-reference."_ This is irrelevant to the target function of std::thread, for which, std::thread could had supported both, by value and by reference. In other words, std::forward<T> will forward either by value or by reference, depending on the parameter types in the target function.

Comment: @alex35833 No, `std::forward` can't make a distinction between values and references. It always results in a glvalue, never a prvalue, which is what would be needed to distinguish values from reference. But template argument deduction doesn't allow distinguishing prvalues from xvalues. Using the target function to determine value/reference doesn't work because in general you can't inspect parameter types of a callable (it could be generic). Also, the decayed objects, if any, must be constructed in the calling thread to avoid data races. In the target function parameters would be too late.

Comment: @alex35833 Also, even if you could do it that way, suppose you have a target function taking a `const int&`. Do you expect such a function to always take the argument given to `std::thread` directly by-reference? What if the argument is a prvalue? Do you really want the `const int&` to refer to the temporary object that will be destroyed immediately? But you can't distinguish prvalue from glvalue in the call to `std::thread`'s constructor, so we are back to what I outlined above.

Comment: "Using the target function to determine value/reference doesn't work because in general you can't inspect parameter types of a callable (it could be generic)." I am new to c++. Do you have an example? So far, I see that the thread constructor has full info regarding the types of arguments of the target function (and they are all part of its mangled name).

Comment: @alex35833 Simplest example is probably `std::thread([](auto x){}, 0)`: `[](auto x){}` can be called with any type of argument and it's `operator()` can be specialized so that `x` has any arbitrary type, including reference types, e.g. `[](auto x){}.operator<const int&>(0)`. Name mangling is irrelevant. The problem here lies in overload resolution, nothing to do with linking.

Comment: My main point is that it is very easy (and in fact the natural way) to support both, by value and by reference in std::thread. The only reason it is not supported is because of a requirement by the standard to to the *unnatural* thing and throw in std::decay. This is NOT the reason given by Stroustrup.

Comment: @alex35833 But you can't, for the reasons discussed above. Deduction at the call site can't make that distinction without a wrapper and the parameter types of the target functions can't be used, because that is generally not available information. That's quite generic for all interfaces of this form, which is what Stroustrup probably means with "_This implies_".  And then further, specifically for threads but also many similar interfaces, you wouldn't generally want to naively choose the reference-ness of the target parameter types if you could, as it would not behave as expected.

Comment: `std::thread([](auto x){}, 0)` is not an example, because the (template) function ends up to have its full type (including its parameters) deduced from the argument. Practically, this is no different from a "normal" function specifically declared with an `int` parameter, i.e. pass by value.

Comment: @alex35833 There is no way for the `std::thread` constructor to recognize that calling the callable with an `int` argument will call a function taking `int` by-value. The core language doesn't provide any way of retrieving that information.

Comment: std::thread does not call its target function without knowing fully its parameters values. Otherwise, the call couldn't be implemented in practice. It should promote and convert etc. and in c++ also pass by reference (i.e. pass the pointer of the argument) according to the types of the formal parameters. There is calling to any function, unless the type of the function and its parameters are completely resolved at compiled time and actually they become an inherent part of the instantiated function. Two *different* functions will be generated for the same generic lambda, if differ by arguments.

Comment: @alex35833 The compiler emits different functions for each specialization, so yes, the _compiler_ knows what the actual parameters after overload resolution are. However, in C++ the language itself, all `std::thread`'s constructor does internally is call the target callable with something like `target(/*args...*/)` (or rather `std::invoke(/*target*/, /*args*/)`).

Comment: @alex35833 The compiler knows to which specializations of `target` these calls resolve, but there is nothing in the C++ core language to obtain that information in C++ user code and generally the standard library is specified so that it can be implemented (for the most part) in normal C++. And all of that aside, it wouldn't make semantic sense to base the reference/value decision on the reference-ness of the parameters, even you could retrieve them, as I mentioned above. So that's not something to even consider.

Comment: The std::thread constructor generates very different code depending whether the target function accept by value or by reference. This is required anyway. The requirement by the standard to "decay" the reference, means that it will pass a reference to a "decaying" copy of the reference. Still, the target function expects a reference and it will get one. and If the target function expects a value, it will get a value. A call is always generated depending on the parameter types (either by value or by reference) and it is impossible to do without full info about the the target call.